# Prohibiting an item's margin to overflow its container

Tags: css

I have a DIV that contains user-generated contents. These contents may and will start with an item that has a `margin-top` and that `margin-top` overflows the container so that there will be a gap between the container and preceding elements. I found out you can set the container to either `display:inline-block`, `float:left`/`right` or give it a `padding-top` value.

If you do one of the first 2 options the container will shrink its width to its contained elements. Padding-top is not an option because of the gap that the padding will generate. Basically you could set a specific width to the container but the problem with that is that there's a templating system with 60+ layouts and I cannot edit all of them.

So I was wondering, do you see any CSS-way to get rid of that margin-overflowing problem *or* the shrinking-problem here?

Comment: Could you maybe provide some code and an example @ [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? It would be easier to understand what exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways is to add "overflow: hidden;" to its parent. But it not always an option if you have content that you want to overflow parent's boundaries.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cLxhE/1/

Another way is to use pseudo-elements to clear it. But it will not work in IE7 and below.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cLxhE/2/

Answer (score -1):

You could add this to the top of your container div before the user added contents:

```
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

Then give it a height of 0px.